# Netbeans PHP breakpoints strange behavior

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

I have disabled all breakpoints but it is still stopping!!

[image]

Why it happening! Is it a bug? I tried to re-enable and and then disable it, but still it stops!

Comment: Save and restart your IDE?

Comment: The bug is still happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Tools->options->PHP->Debugging`

Untick checkbox `Stop at first Line`

[image]

Comment: It saved me a lot of time! Thank you for this glue!